# Confused with JavaScript/HTML shadowbox for photos

Tags: javascript, html, css, photo, shadowbox

I am new to web design/coding and am working on a personal website. I'm trying to create a shadowbox in JavaScript... I copied code from shadowbox-js.com but am throwing up an error on line 8 in Dreamweaver. On top of that I'm confused on how to code the photos in on the HTML file. I have a thumbnail photo that I would like to be able to be clickable so you can enlarge it in a popup window. I created a enlarged version of the photo (named it differently than the thumbnail, will correct that later) but am confused on how to code them into the HTML file. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is a codepen of the files:

[https://codepen.io/AJ2021/pen/pQzmOR#*=*](https://codepen.io/AJ2021/pen/pQzmOR#_=_)

Line 100 of the CSS is in a new file called shadowbox.css.

The line in the HTML I'm confused with is:

```
<section> 
    <font face="Lucida Bright">
    <center><h1 id="pagename">Gallery</h1></center>


    <div id="gallery">
    <!-- Here are the gallery thumbnails -->
    <a href="_images/php_family_marina.png"
    rel="shadowbox[picture]" title="My family at Sunbury Marina"
    <img src="tmb_Lawton_Family.png">

    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you missing `>` and `</a>` for `<a>` tag and call it with `shadowbox()` not `Shadowbox.init()`

```js
shadowbox();
```

```css
#gallery img {padding: 10px; margin: 5px;background: green}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/shadowbox-js@3.0.3/source/shadowbox.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/shadowbox-js@3.0.3/source/shadowbox.min.js"></script>

<div id="gallery">

  <a href="https://i.postimg.cc/Kjn5GpVF/full-a.jpg" rel="shadowbox[picture]" title="a">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/mZMjyhrq/thumb-a.jpg">
  </a>

  <a href="https://i.postimg.cc/PrQM0cYQ/full-b.jpg" rel="shadowbox[picture]" title="b">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/4Ng5LZ73/thumb-b.jpg">
  </a>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting errors and when I chaged shadowbox.init() to shadowbox() it put that code in my website so at the top of the page before the nav bar, that wording appears. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Here is my code

Comment: https://codepen.io/AJ2021/pen/PxZwaN.  The errors are on line 14, 42, 46, 52, 54, 56.

Comment: I figured out line 14, it needed to be deleted.

Comment: Same goes for line 52, 54, 56...  Dreamweaver says line 42 and 46, that an alt attribute must be presented on <img> elements. Not sure how to do that but as it stands it seems to work. All I need now is to figure out how to space the photos out.The code shadowbox() is still showing at the top before the nav bar when previewing the site.

Comment: now you missing `</script>` after `shadowbox();` :D here fixed code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rQxxyJ

Comment: for space use margin and padding, add `#gallery img {padding: 10px; margin: 5px;background: green}`

Comment: Thanks for your help... I added the code to the file but the CSS code isn't working. It doesn't add anything to my photos such as spacing and background color... It works in codepen though. Could it be I'm using a different computer than the one I started it on. I'm using a networked computer and my files are almost all available anywhere (via networked computers). For some odd reason though I can't access my shadowbox.cc and shadowbox.js files from here. Only the computer I started it on.

Comment: line 42 and 43 still has that error: an alt attribute must be presented on <img> elements. Any idea why Dreamweaver is throwing it up?

Comment: There is a problem... I did what you said to get the spacing for the gallery pictures but for some odd reason it didn't do anything... I wish I could sent a screen shot of what I mean but I can't seem to find out how. Everything else works!

Comment: What do you mean? Also my links in the nav bar aren’t working... home page is actually index.html not home.html but even when I changed it, it won’t take me to the page... It’s just does nothing :(

Comment: I dont know about your link/file navigation, but see your actual problem with `shadowbox` is solved. it better mark this solved and create new post for different problem

Comment: Hmm, ok... What about the style? I’m confused. I put the CSS code in main.css. Did I need to put it in the html page.